# node server not running - throwing process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run node express in c9.io but I am having problem it gives me this error I can't figure it out. I am getting this error message.

```
$ node app.js
Server is running

/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTful Routing/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost.restful_blog_app localhost.restful_blog_app:27017
    at errnoException (dns.js:27:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:78:26)

var bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
mongoose       = require("mongoose"),
express        = require("express"),
app            = express();

    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost.restful_blog_app");
    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.use(express.static("public"));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
       console.log("Server is running"); 
    });
```

Comment: The url `localhost.restful_blog_app` is probably wrong

Comment: i checked the path they are correct.

Comment: `mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost.restful_blog_app");` what is the database name ?

Comment: I think it's `mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/restful_blog_app");`

Comment: OMG YOU ARE A SAVIOR!!!!!! HOW CAN I REP YOU!?

Comment: @spaceDog I guess by stopping to shout, accepting his answer and upvoting it as an extra bonus.

Comment: thank guys! Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's `mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/restful_blog_app");`

Answer (score 0):

You should also remember to start the database before running the server. And in case you still have issues, you should try to change localhost into 127.0.0.1 instead.